# google api for glorious info box?

Tags: api, google-api, freebase

I'm guessing this info is privileged since I couldn't find anything on Google's listed APIs.  In fact I'd be amazed if it wasn't proprietary securely fastened Google magic, but thought I'd ask anyway.

Is there an Google API for the information appearing when you do a basic search for say an Actress or Rockband?  You know the box that appears to the right of the results if google figures out exactly what you're looking for. (I'm specifically interested in musicians despite the example below)

I.e.

https://www.google.com/search?q=woody+allen

[image]

I can get similar milage using Freebase, but Google's is always better.  For example, It'll even pull upcoming events if it's a Musician, etc.

Comment: freebase contains a lot of the same information you're looking for.

Comment: SerpApi has a knowledge graph API: https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph

Answer (score 4):

The [Freebase Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) contains the bulk of what you're looking for.

e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/woody_allen`

Comment: Link no longer works. According to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798009/is-there-an-api-for-the-google-answer-boxes) this was depreciated

Comment: Yes, the Freebase APIs were retired years ago. The Google Knowledge Graph Search API and the Wikidata API are probably the two closest replacements, but neither is a perfect fit.